# Warcraft 3 on Ubuntu 19.04, graphics not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, games

I installed Warcraft 3 on Ubuntu 19.04 using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1114329/983430) (except right before installing Warcraft, I had to redo the changes in `winecfg`, since they had reverted for some reason). When I try to run the game with

```
wine Warcraft\ III.exe
```

I get an error

```
Unable to initialize graphics. Please ensure your operating system and display drivers are up to date.
```

I tried

```
wine Warcraft\ III.exe -nativefullscr

wine Warcraft\ III.exe -Direct3D9
```

and changing `resheight` and `reswidth` to my native screen resolution, but without any change (so I changed it back to the original values).

I also tried

```
wine Warcraft\ III.exe -graphicsapi OpenGL
```

which only gives me a black screen (but with music playing on the background and the game menu reacting with sounds to hotkeys, so the game (at least initially) runs, just with no graphic output).

I also tried switching to open-source drivers and repeat all the attempts with them, but that only results in me always getting random colors/lines on the screen and I have to power the laptop off (except in the case when I change the registry configuration, in which case the game crashes without any error message right after launch).

Comment: Hey, man :)
Did you manage to resolve your issue? I ran into the same problem, even though on OpenSUSE. Please, let me know :)

Comment: Hi, no, sorry, I haven't figured it out yet. I'm just waiting if someone else does right now, maybe I'll have more time in the future... or at least I hope I will. If you find out, please let me know what works. Good luck. 

Comment: Btw, I tried to download the game from a torrent tracker. It wasn't installation, just archive, unrar and run the exe file. It ran smoothly. (Only had no sound at the beginning but I changed the audio settings on `winecfg` and it got fixed.) ... However, this is only single player and LAN, it won't work on Battle.net :( ...

Comment: One last thing - have you tried this tutorial? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHkniTQFRr8 ... I see the guy there manages to run it on Linux, and he did it via the official launchers from Blizzard - which is what we want as well :) ... And also it's a recent one, not some from years ago :)

Comment: Thanks, that's really nice of you to find that, I'll try it in a few days.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I got around to it only now. The tutorial from youtube doesn't work for me - `vulkaninfo` shows `failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED`. I'll try your answer when I get around to it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer to that as I was able to successfully run the game, even though it wasn't with Ubuntu at the end.

===

I wanted to do it with OpenSUSE Tumbleweed, cause I want rolling release distro. Tried for almost a month to install it on the laptop with no success. I tried then with Ubuntu, but after the installed crashed twice - I left that option too.

(I think the hardware is causing the problems in the above two cases, I don't blame the distros.)

Then - I installed Manjaro. It ran from the first try.
After that - I installed wine staging and then dxvk, from these two tutorials:

https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/install-wine-staging-on-linux/

https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/set-up-dxvk-in-wine-on-linux/

Setup the virtual desktop in `winecfg` - with resolution ~1000x800.

Then - installed both launchers from Blizzard - the Battle.net and the Warcraft 3 ones.

After that - login in both launchers. It's tricky, but doable. This tutorial shows some useful info for the process :D

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHkniTQFRr8&t=500s

(I didn't follow the tutorial, just sharing it because of the useful info about logging in the clients.)

===

Then - removed the setting for virtual desktop and ran the game (WC3). However - I got black screen and crash after a couple of seconds.

What I did to resolve is:

- Launch `winetricks`.
- From it - installed `corefonts`.
- And from it again - I installed `ie8` and then `dxvk (latest)`.

And when I launched it again - I had graphics and sound, and the videos played as well.

But the video was shifted to the left, so I tried to launch the game with
`wine [path-to-warcraft3.exe] -opengl` - and then it ran with no issues.

(Considering the fact I have integrated Intel video :D ...)

Good luck ;)

Comment: Part 1: Thanks a lot, but this one doesn't work for me either - the tutorial to install Wine Staging results in `wget: unable to resolve host address ‘repos.wine-staging.com’`, so instead I installed Wine Staging with [this tutorial](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/09/how-to-install-wine-staging-development.html), where I accidentally followed the steps for Ubuntu 19.10 (but after finishing them, I did the steps for Ubuntu 19.04).

Comment: Part 2: Before installing `winehq-staging`, I checked in Software Updater if I didn't have repositories for Ubuntu 19.10 added by accident, but there were only repos for Ubuntu 19.04, so it's probably all fine. When installing `dxvk` according to the second tutorial, it showed unfulfilled dependencies, so before installing the packages, I had to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`.

Comment: Part 3: The problem I didn't get past was when I tried to install Warcraft, it showed `We're having trouble launching Battle.net Update Agent. Please wait one minute and try again. If it happens again, try restarting your computer or reinstalling Battle.net.` (None of those three advices worked.) (I'm upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10 now so if it still doesn't work there, I'll start another question later, I want to keep this one for Ubuntu 19.04 only.) Thanks though, I'm happy it worked for you at least. 