# How do I install 64 bit wine on ubuntu?

Tags: wine, 64-bit, winetricks

I have looked all over for guides and instruction on how to install 64 bit wine but no matter which guide I follow when I install wine it always installs 32 bit wine (it creates it under ~/.wine32). Could I please get a simple step by step process in how to install 64 bit wine?

For example how do I need to change these [fantastic step-by-step instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114328/how-to-install-battle-net-and-run-blizzard-games-on-ubuntu-18-10) to install 64 bit wine instead of 32 bit wine?

I'm using 64 bit ubuntu version 16.04.

Comment: On this site ? https://vitux.com/how-to-install-wine-on-ubuntu/ Otherwise, what's your ubuntu version?

Comment: 16.04, as I stated in my post.

Comment: I've already tried that, when I try it I get the following

`me@computer:~$ sudo apt install wine64`
`[sudo] password for me: `
`Reading package lists... Done`
`Building dependency tree `      
`Reading state information... Done`
`Package wine64 is a virtual package provided by:`
`  winehq-staging 4.15~xenial`
`  winehq-stable 4.0.2~xenial`     
` winehq-devel 4.15~xenial`
    `You should explicitly select one to install.`

    `E: Package 'wine64' has no installation candidate`

Comment: sudo dpkg --get-selections > selections.txt

Comment: And look at if it's present.

Comment: It is not, but there is wine64-development

Comment: some programs might not work in 64 bit, if you need it just add WINEARCH=win64 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine64 using winetricks option

Comment: systemctl | grep -i error

Comment: dmesg | grep -i failure

Comment: It seems like setting these 2 environment variables has done the job, after changing them and then running winetricks it generated ~/.wine64 and is now installing the program I wanted to install. Thanks very much.

Comment: that's works? I think you don't need winehq package cause same programs need same dll to handle it and wasting time and a bad mojo to me :)

Comment: Yeah, that worked, program installed and runs fine using wine64.

Comment: glad to hear thar, can you add your own answer :) :)